# Windows Update Fails KB4579311

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I've tried to update Win10 many times but it keeps failing.  I've run the manual install and it gives me a message that the update was not installed but no reason.

I've run windows update and rebooted many times.

I have plenty of disk space and have run sfc, dism.  I've cleaned c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution and catroot2.

I'm running Win10 2004 build 19041.508

I've tried running the manual install.  This is the update I'm trying to install windows10.0-kb4579311-x64_9cc8221b0ed1bc799278d029c4edadf785920da9.msu

The log file is too large to attach here so I included only the last part which contains the error logs.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
2020/10/17 16:12:53.1315470 11256 15328 Handler         CBS called Progress with state=7, ticks=1000, total=1000
2020/10/17 16:12:53.1318049 14088 5812  UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : NotifyClient (5812)(0) called for update id EB9B69B7-F375-411D-9396-E6D5D0238C40, code = Update progress, percent complete = 100
2020/10/17 16:12:53.1320046 11256 15328 Handler         CBS called Terminate
2020/10/17 16:13:12.5161236 14088 13948 UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : Update EB9B69B7-F375-411D-9396-E6D5D0238C40.501 failure delegate invoked.
2020/10/17 16:13:12.5161898 11256 13196 Handler         Completed install of CBS update with type=0, requiresReboot=0, installerError=1, hr=0x80070005
2020/10/17 16:13:12.5163775 14088 14420 UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : NotifyClient (14420)(0) called for update id EB9B69B7-F375-411D-9396-E6D5D0238C40, code = Update failed, percent complete = 100
2020/10/17 16:13:12.5164127 14088 14420 Agent           LogHistory called. idUpdate={EB9B69B7-F375-411D-9396-E6D5D0238C40}.501, resultMapped=80070005, resultUnMapped=80070005
2020/10/17 16:13:12.5165431 13504 9624  ComApi          Deployment callback complete for UpdateID = eb9b69b7-f375-411d-9396-e6d5d0238c40, callback code = 8, CallbackInfo cookie length = 0
2020/10/17 16:13:12.5171403 14088 14420 Agent           WU client logged Install deloyment history, caller = wusa, update EB9B69B7-F375-411D-9396-E6D5D0238C40.501, classification 0FA1201D-4330-4FA8-8AE9-B877473B6441
2020/10/17 16:13:13.3828845 11256 13196 Handler         * END *   CBS Install
2020/10/17 16:13:13.5934562 14088 1380  UDP             *FAILED* [80070005] Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : Installing for Top level update id EB9B69B7-F375-411D-9396-E6D5D0238C40.501, bundled update id AEDB28BA-8F6E-4F0C-9001-C663F639A206.501 [CUpdateDeploymentJob::DeploySingleUpdateInternal:2790]
2020/10/17 16:13:13.5934660 14088 1380  UDP             *FAILED* [8024200B] Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : Installing for Top level update id EB9B69B7-F375-411D-9396-E6D5D0238C40.501, bundled update id AEDB28BA-8F6E-4F0C-9001-C663F639A206.501 [CUpdateDeploymentJob::DeploySingleUpdateInternal:2807]
2020/10/17 16:13:13.5934867 14088 1380  WIL             *FAILED* [8024200B] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\engine\updatedeploymentprovider\lib\updatedeploymentjob.cpp, line = 2809
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6018368 14088 1380  UDP             Mutex will be closed.  index = 0, HANDLE = 0x00000A6C
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6018639 14088 1380  UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : Method failed for update EB9B69B7-F375-411D-9396-E6D5D0238C40.501, hrDeploy = 0x8024200b
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6018720 14088 1380  UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : Update EB9B69B7-F375-411D-9396-E6D5D0238C40.501 failure delegate invoked.
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6116287 14088 1380  UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : Job complete delegate invoked.
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6116405 14088 1380  UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : Ending Installing updates, CallerId = wusa, Exit code = 0x00000000
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6118123 14088 5384  UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : WaitForEnd invoked for deployment job. Beginning the wait now!
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6118282 14088 10864 UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : NotifyClient (10864)(0) called with Deployment callback code = Job complete, reboot status = no reboot
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6119352 13504 9624  ComApi           Install ClientId = wusa
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6119387 13504 9624  ComApi          Install call complete (succeeded = 0, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 1, cancelled = 0, unaccounted = 0
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6119725 14088 5384  UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : WaitForEnd for deployment job completed. Job state = Complete
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6119863 14088 5384  UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : CallbackWorker returning successfully.
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6119960 13504 9624  ComApi          Reboot required = False
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6119979 13504 9624  ComApi          Call error code = 0x80240022
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6119991 13504 9624  ComApi          * END *   Install ClientId = wusa
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6120401 14088 10824 Agent           WU client calls back to deploy call {6E45407D-CB96-4FEF-8030-900898048D1C} with code Call complete and error 0 
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6121280 14088 1804  UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : WaitForEnd invoked for deployment job. Beginning the wait now!
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6121636 14088 1804  UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : WaitForEnd for deployment job completed. Job state = Complete
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6121688 14088 1804  Agent           WU client update deployment job FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 end wait complete.
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6121771 14088 1804  UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : Per-job deployment completed = Yes"
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6121830 14088 1804  UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : EndUpdateDeployment invoked for job. Job complete = Yes, erase Job = True
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6121890 14088 1804  Agent           WU client EndUpdateDeployment for deployment job FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 complete.
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6121937 14088 1804  Agent           WU client update deployment job FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 deployment result. hr = 0x00000000
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6122034 14088 1804  UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : FinalRelease for deployment job.
2020/10/17 16:13:13.6122107 14088 1804  UDP             Deployment job Id FE4717AD-E16A-4B5F-9E10-B9687C34E9D1 : WaitForEnd invoked for deployment job. Beginning the wait now!
```

Comment: That update installed on both my production machines, Try updating all of your drivers, restart and try again.

Comment: Unfortunately I've done that without success.

Comment: Perhaps wait a week (or perhaps next Patch Tuesday) and let auto updates try again .

Comment: That will happen by default if I can't find a solution or reason.  I'd like to know why this happened. :)

Comment: I have looked around about this and I have not found any reason not covered by the above.

Comment: That update is not on my Windows Insider machine and so may be superseded in the next feature update due out next month.

Comment: 19041.508 - Was released last month.  You are missing at least 4 cumulative updates (some weee optional) which means you haven’t installed a single update in a month.  I would generate logs for Windows Update (Microsoft has documented how this is done) to determine the reason Windows hasn’t been patch in a month

Comment: I suspect that feature update (20H2) would fail to install in the systems current state

Comment: @Ramhound it appears to be updating fine except for this one.  Here is the update history and the only failure is this KB.

https://imgur.com/a/ThJpFoI

Comment: @glez - The 508 was released last month.  There have been multiple cumulative updates since September 8 2020; Windows Update history might still show your update history with those failures but (c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution) actually contained that history so when you cleaned it you also wiped your update history

Comment: No idea why they are not installed.  Update is on auto and I’ve run it mannually without it finding any updates over the last couple weeks for driver updates and such.  Ive run update at least 6 times today alone.  Perhaps this is a cumulative update containing those.  Ive always found win update to be a bit flakey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error code 0x80070005 means Access is denied.
Have you analyzed the CBS Logs in the C:\Windows\Logs\CBS folder?

Friendly greetings

Comment: I just retried and checked the CBS logs.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure what to look for.  It seems to install to 30%, reboot, get to 99% reboot and then rolls back with 2 reboots telling me the updates could not be applied.  I'd post the CBS log file here but its too big.  One thing I noticed after reading some posts is that to update a System Reserved partition needs to have 500MG of free space.  My problem is I don't even have that partition!  This is a win7 upgrade in place.

Comment: Other updates have applied successfully.

Comment: Can you upload the cbs folder on OneDrive, Google Drive or wetransfer.com?

Copy the CBS folder to your desktop, zip it and then upload it.

I would look at the log files, but since it is already very late for me now, it will take a while until I report back here.

Comment: A number of Windows 7 upgrade in place to Windows 10 eventually need a Repair Install to fix things. Something to consider.

Comment: It may be that the update mentioned can cause problems for some people. But still a look at log files would be good and i can possibly see where it fails.

@glez can you upload a picture from your disk management to see the partitions on your pc? Upload it on imgur and share the link.

Comment: @Teckie_Boy.  Here you go.  Thanks for the help.  Its getting late here also. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UfZj5Ru8dWdPyNOpIR4TAtwBVCTt6jCI?usp=sharing

Comment: Here's the disk layout.

https://imgur.com/a/lxba4l4

Comment: Thanks. 
The system reserved partition is on your pc the recovery partition. 

The update fails for this reason:
`2020-10-17 18:32:26, Error      [0x018007] CSI    00001b5f (F) Failed execution of queue item Installer: Generic Command ({81a34a10-4256-436a-89d6-794b97ca407c}) with HRESULT HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(14109).  Failure will be ignored: The failure was encountered during rollback; installer is reliable[gle=0x80004005]`

The update tries to update files from the Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) but access is denied. The WAS belongs to the Internet Information Services (IIS).

Comment: `2020-10-17 18:32:27, Error                 CSI    00001bf0 (F) Generic Command ErrorCode: 80004005 Executable: lodctr.exe ExitCode: 1010 Phase: 38 Mode: Install (downgrade) Component: Microsoft-Windows-WAS-NetFxEnvironment-GC, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=amd64, versionScope=NonSxS[gle=0x80004005]`

Comment: @glez Have you see my answer from yesterday?

Comment: @Teckie_Boy Just saw this.  I'm grateful you found the root cause. So IIS is the problem.  I don't use it on this machine so should I uninstall it?

Comment: If you do not need the iis, uninstall it and try the update again.

Comment: Worked!  Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: It seems this has caused a lot of people problems.

https://www.techradar.com/news/disastrous-windows-10-update-is-breaking-some-pcs

Answer (score 1):

Below from Microsoft is the purpose of update KB4579311.

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4579311/windows-10-update-kb4579311#:~:text=Highlights,when%20Windows%20performs%20basic%20operations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4579311/windows-10-update-kb4579311#:%7E:text=Highlights,when%20Windows%20performs%20basic%20operations).

> Updates to improve security when using Microsoft Office products.
> Updates for verifying usernames and passwords. Updates to improve
> security when Windows performs basic operations.

It is acceptable if not installed and it will come back in the next feature update.

However, it is causing problems for some users.

https://betanews.com/2020/10/17/windows-10-kb4579311-cumulative-update-problems/